# Issue regarding core.apexpages.el.adapters.RuntimeTypeMetadataELAdapter

Tags: visualforce

I have an outputPanel that saves if it's in one spot, but throws the core.apexpages.el.adapters.RuntimeTypeMetadataELAdapter error if I put it in another spot.  See below.

The reason I want to move it is because it makes sense for this section to be at the top of the other section.  This section has new lines, which should be displayed to the user as soon as the section becomes visible, while the existing lines should appear below.

It's worth noting that if I change the inputField tags to inputText tags and use a global variable I don't get the error, but since these inputs are to be used for multiple lines I'd like to keep them as inputField tags... particular because this works just fine in the spot it works in.  Also worth noting is the reason for the multiple form tags and outputPanel wrapper:  the outputPanel is re-rendered when a button is clicked, and the form holds the rendered tag (and is required for the buttons).

Existing layout that works:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!mapVirtOLIs}" var="existVOLI" id="repeatExistVOLIs">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Scenario {!existVOLI} - {!mapVirtOLIs[existVOLI][0].Freight_Quote__r.Name}" mode="detail">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
                <input type="button" class="btn" value="Choose Scenario for Pipeline" id="{!existVOLI}_{!opp.Id}" onclick="setVOLIasOrder(this);" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!mapVirtOLIs[existVOLI]}" var="li" columnsWidth="40%, 20%, 20%, 20%">
                <apex:column headerValue="Product">{!li.Customer_Portal_Pricebook_Entry__r.Product_Code__c}</apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Quantity">{!li.Quantity__c}</apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Unit Price"><apex:outputField value="{!li.Unit_Cost__c}"></apex:outputField></apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Total Price"><apex:outputField value="{!li.Total_Cost__c}"></apex:outputField></apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:repeat>
<apex:outputPanel id="thenewVOLIsForm">
    <apex:form rendered="{!AND(NOT(ISNULL(newVOLIs)), newVOLIs.size > 0)}">
        <apex:pageBlock title="Scenario {!newVOLIs[0].Group_Number__c}" mode="detail">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
                <apex:commandButton action="{!addNewVOLIToCurrent}" value="Add Product to Scenario" status="spinwheel" reRender="thenewVOLIsForm" />
                <apex:commandButton action="{!saveCurrentVOLIs}" value="Add Freight and Save Scenario" status="spinwheel" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!newVOLIs}" var="li">
                <apex:column headerValue="Enter Product">
                    <apex:selectList value="{!li.Customer_Portal_Pricebook_Entry__c}" size="1" onchange="getPricebookPrice(this);" styleClass="{!opp.Id}">
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!scenarioOptions}" />
                    </apex:selectList>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Enter Quantity">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!li.Quantity__c}" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Enter Price (if different than pricebook)">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!li.Unit_Cost__c}" />
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Desired page layout that doesn't work (copy the  section and paste it above the  section):

```
<apex:outputPanel id="thenewVOLIsForm">
    <apex:form rendered="{!AND(NOT(ISNULL(newVOLIs)), newVOLIs.size > 0)}">
        <apex:pageBlock title="Scenario {!newVOLIs[0].Group_Number__c}" mode="detail">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
                <apex:commandButton action="{!addNewVOLIToCurrent}" value="Add Product to Scenario" status="spinwheel" reRender="thenewVOLIsForm" />
                <apex:commandButton action="{!saveCurrentVOLIs}" value="Add Freight and Save Scenario" status="spinwheel" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!newVOLIs}" var="li">
                <apex:column headerValue="Enter Product">
                    <apex:selectList value="{!li.Customer_Portal_Pricebook_Entry__c}" size="1" onchange="getPricebookPrice(this);" styleClass="{!opp.Id}">
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!scenarioOptions}" />
                    </apex:selectList>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Enter Quantity">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!li.Quantity__c}" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Enter Price (if different than pricebook)">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!li.Unit_Cost__c}" />
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:outputPanel>
<apex:repeat value="{!mapVirtOLIs}" var="existVOLI" id="repeatExistVOLIs">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Scenario {!existVOLI} - {!mapVirtOLIs[existVOLI][0].Freight_Quote__r.Name}" mode="detail">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
                <input type="button" class="btn" value="Choose Scenario for Pipeline" id="{!existVOLI}_{!opp.Id}" onclick="setVOLIasOrder(this);" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!mapVirtOLIs[existVOLI]}" var="li" columnsWidth="40%, 20%, 20%, 20%">
                <apex:column headerValue="Product">{!li.Customer_Portal_Pricebook_Entry__r.Product_Code__c}</apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Quantity">{!li.Quantity__c}</apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Unit Price"><apex:outputField value="{!li.Unit_Cost__c}"></apex:outputField></apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Total Price"><apex:outputField value="{!li.Total_Cost__c}"></apex:outputField></apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:repeat>
```

Additional info:

newVOLIs = a list of records from a custom object that mirrors OpportunityLineItem called Virtual_OpportunityLineItem__c;

mapVirtOLIs = a map with the key being a string (numbers for the scenario) and the values being a list of all Virtual_OpportunityLineItem__c records for each scenario

Thanks!

Comment: If this was my page, I would try using a different name for the second "li" var e.g. "li2" as the variables are referencing different types and I am not sure of how Visualforce handles variables of the same name. (Unlikely to work but worth a quick try.)

Comment: Holy crap that worked.  Any idea why though?  Shouldn't Visualforce have complained either way?

Comment: Visualforce probably does the simplest thing about the scope of "var" of only having one scope per page and keying by name. So while Visualforce ought to give us programmers more help up front it doesn't today. Anyway, good that you can work-around the problem.

Comment: @KeithC , man. After 6 years you added this comment. Thank you.